# how to give a parameters to a function in C

Tags: c

I don't know how to give a parameters to a function. I wrote a body, as you can see in my program below. Any answers and explanations appreciated!

```
    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <stdint.h>


    // Ceramic Resonator
    #ifndef F_CPU
    #define F_CPU 3686400 // 4MHz
    #endif

    // UART
    #define UART_BAUD_RATE 9600
    #define UART_BAUD_CALC(UART_BAUD_RATE,F_OSC) ((F_CPU)/((UART_BAUD_RATE)*16L)-1)




    int decode( int rcv[i], ... ){  !!!
        int returnValue;
        if ((rcv[0] == rcv[1]) && (rcv[0] == rcv[2]) && (rcv[1] == rcv[2])){
            returnValue = 0;
            //return UDR0;
        }
        else if   (rcv[1] != rcv[2] && (rcv[0] == rcv[1])){
            returnValue = 1;
            //UDR0 = 01;

        }
        else if  (rcv[1] != rcv[2] && (rcv[0] == rcv[2])){
            returnValue = 2;
            //UDR0 = 02;

        }
        else if  (rcv[0] != rcv[1] && (rcv[1] == rcv[2])){
            returnValue = 3;
            //UDR0 = 03;

        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    int main(void){

        // USART
        UBRR0H =(uint8_t) (UART_BAUD_CALC(UART_BAUD_RATE,F_CPU) >>8);
        UBRR0L =(uint8_t) UART_BAUD_CALC(UART_BAUD_RATE,F_CPU);

        UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0); // enable receiver and transmitter,
        UCSR0C = (3<<UCSZ00); // 8 bit (default: asynchronous, no parity, 1 stop-bit)

        DDRC = (1<<5); // set data direction register bit 5 to one, this means PC5 is configured as output
        PORTC = (1<<5); // set output value of PC5 to High-Level (Source Current, 5V to ground)
        // VARIABLES
        //uint8_t get;
        // PROGRAM

        unsigned char code[3] = {'x','y','z'}; // Here you need to write your code
        unsigned char rcv[3]={'0','0','0'}; // received data

        int i = 0;

        int retVal;

        while(1){
            i = 0;
            for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
                // wait for empty transmit buffer 
                //while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
                // wait for data to be received
                while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));
                /* put data into buffer, sends the data*/
                {  
                    code[i]= UDR0  ;
                }

                //while(1) // forever
                //{


                PORTC ^= (1<<5); //this is for LED

                // get received data from buffer
                rcv[i] = code[i];


            }
            retVal = decode(int rcv[i], ... ); !!!
            // wait for empty transmit buffer
            while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
            // put data into buffer, sends the data
            /*if ((rcv[0] == rcv[1]) && (rcv[0] == rcv[2]) && (rcv[1] == rcv[2]))*/
            UDR0 = retVal;             
        }

    }
```

Comment: use pointers, read more here http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: If you don't even know how to pass parameters between functions, I'm betting dollars to donuts you didn't actually write that code.

Comment: Don't use TABs, just a free advice :-)  More serious: Leave out all code, and especially empty lines, that add nothing to you question.  In this case the code could have been just a few lines.  @FerretallicA Very funny!

Comment: @meaning-matters any particular reason you are discouraging the use of tabs? They're pretty idiomatic to indent code with.

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."*   (aka, read any "Intro to C" book)

Comment: @H2CO3 It's actually the fact that TAB widths differ that results in messy code visuals.  For example many people have a 4 space TAB width, shells are often at 8.  If you then for example do a `diff` in a shell, the output looks like shit, by default.  In general I like to stay away from things that are context sensitive, even worse when you can't see it, like TAB white space.  About all editor have a setting to indent with spaces when actually typing a TAB, and quite a few even delete the indent width as well; ergo, there is no real need to use TABs.

Comment: @meaning-matters I see. But aren't TABs supposed to insert TAB characters in any sane code editor? Then the reader of the code can view it with whatever width settings he prefers.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, many sane editors/IDEs have this TAB-2-spaces option I mentioned (Xcode, Eclipse, Visual Studio, ...), and this is used a lot by sane developer like me :-)  Your question reminds me of other issues with TABs.  1) Traditionally TAB width is 8, but K&R code indentation width is 4.  This means you get a mix of TABs and spaces.  In the cleanest way: N TABs followed by 0 or 4 spaces.  Indentation is broken on all but TAB width 8.  2) People often use tabs within lines, e.g. to left align comments on different lines.  This means that the actual space created by the TAB is variable....

Comment: @meaning-matters I agree with the second point, but again, in C, one should use the Kernel coding style. Basically that's K&R with tabs being tabs and not arbitrary nonsense :P Also, Xcode and Visual Studio as a sane IDE? Very funny indeed. (I don't question your knowledge and experience though, but those IDEs make me cry.)

Comment: @H2CO3 ....which leads to mess when displayed on anything other than the original TAB width.  3) There can be spaces inside the TAB created white space.  4) When mixing TABs and spaces makes reindenting lines cumbersome.  With TAB width 8 and indentation 4, you're at one time removing a TAB and need to add spaces, need to remove the 4 spaces and then add add TAB (to avoid having spaces inside the TABed white space).

Comment: Also when you reindent code that has TAB inside the line, these alignment point also jump all over the place.  TABs are a mess, and you'll very soon end up with files that have weird mixture of TABs and spaces.

Comment: @meaning-matters eeeeer I never said it was a good idea to mix spaces and TABs. I meant that I use TABs exclusively for indentation. No spaces. At all.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think Xcode is quite good, but of course Eclipse has more bells and whistles.  I think that editor features that make you code faster/handier are overrated; it's not the coding speed that counts, it's what you code.  Gotta go (to bed for example).  Speak soon and thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @meaning-matters Hi! See you tomorrow (maybe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put pointer to an array and maybe size of it:

change:

```
int decode( int rcv[i], ...)
```

to

```
int decode( unsigned char* rcv)
```

and

```
retVal = decode(int rcv[i], ... ); !!!
```

to

```
retVal = decode(rcv); //rcv is a pointer
```

Comment: Warning 1 passing argument 1 of 'decode' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  87 4 uart1
//also                                                                Message 2 expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'  18 6 uart1

Comment: but they aren't an errors, will it work?

Comment: @Abay yes, it will work. If you don't want to have these errors change int to unisgned chars.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Ari's answer but I feel like I should add that you can use variable parameter lists if that's what you want. You can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html), but this would probably be more work that you require.

**Edit:**
I just noticed the `// Ceramic resonator` comment so I'm guessing you're in an Embedded environment in which case I would strongly recommend a simple pointer like @Ari suggested. The variable parameter list might not be fully implemented on your architecture.